# sqlite3 join-filter order-by performance

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to do a query like that on an sqlite3 database:

```
select node.loc, node.weight from node
inner join filt on (node.id = filt.node_id)
inner join filt T5 on (node.id = T5.node_id)
where (filt.word = 'aaa' and T5.word = 'aasvogel')
order by node.weight desc limit 10;
```

On mysql, such query works fine and fast (<0.2s); on sqlite3, on the same data, it runs for ~2s.

What could be the problem and what can I do to improve its performance?

The files I made to test sqlite3 can be found here: https://github.com/HoverHell/sqlperftst1

The table definitions in particular:

```
CREATE TABLE "node" (                        
    "id" integer PRIMARY KEY,                
    "loc" varchar(255) NOT NULL,             
    "weight" real
);
CREATE INDEX "node_loc" ON "node" ("loc");
CREATE INDEX "node_weight" on "node" ("weight");

CREATE TABLE "filt" (
    "id" integer PRIMARY KEY,
    "node_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "word" varchar(120) NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX "filt_word" ON "filt" ("word");
CREATE INDEX "filt_node_id" ON "filt" ("node_id");
```

UPD: Perofrmance comparison on realistic data and queries:

[image: Perofrmance comparison on realistic data and queries]

Comment: Put the table definitions into the question.

Comment: Done, @CL. Athough those same table definitions are available in the linked repository in two places.

Comment: Please read [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This query can be improved by creating an index on both columns used for lookups:

```
CREATE INDEX filt_word_node_id ON file(word, node_id);
```

However, the shape of tje data is unusual, which makes the query optimizer misestimate the selectivity of the word lookups.
Run [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) to fix this.

Comment: I suppose you meant `CREATE INDEX "filt_word_node_id" ON "filt" ("word", "node_id"); VACUUM; ANALYZE;`? Though that still does not help much; the query still takes over a second.

Comment: It's fast with SQLite 3.8.6.

Comment: thanks, sqlite 3.8 helps a bit; although the performance still diminishes quickly with larger data and with more filter joins.

Comment: You can force another query plan by replacing `from node` with `from node indexed by node_weight` in the query. But this bypasses the query planner for this table and might become slower if the shape of the data changes later.